# Check if a MySQL table contains a value?

Tags: java, mysql, sql

I'm trying to check if my MySQL table has a specific value, to update the value if it does and insert if it doesnt...

Comment: Why is it tagged with [java]?

Comment: Also: It's "Java", not "JAVA".